# Syntax Error with flake8 and Pydantic Constrained Types: constr(regex=)

Tags: python, flake8, pydantic

I use in Python the package pydantic and the linker Flake8. I want to use constr from pydantic with a regular Experssion. Only certain Characters should be passed. (a-z, A-Z, 0-9 and _)

The regular Experssion `"^[a-zA-Z0-9_]*$"` works, but flake8 shows me the following error:

> syntax error in forward annotation '^[a-zA-Z0-9_]*$' flake8(F722)

```
class RedisSettings(BaseModel):
    keyInput: constr(regex="^[a-zA-Z0-9_]*$") = "" 
    keyOutput: constr(regex="^[a-zA-Z0-9_]*$") = ""
```

Can you help me to avoid the Error Message?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

the error here comes from pyflakes which attempts to interpret type annotations as type annotations according to [PEP 484](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/)

the annotations used by pydantic are incompatible with PEP 484 and result in that error.  you can read more about this [in this pyflakes issue](https://github.com/PyCQA/pyflakes/issues/542)

I'd suggest either (1) finding a way to use pydantic which doesn't involve violating PEP 484 or (2) ignoring the errors from pyflakes using flake8's `extend-ignore` / `# noqa: ...` / `per-file-ignores`

---

disclaimer: I am one of the pyflakes maintainers and I am the current flake8 maintainer

Answer (score 4):

You can extract the `constr(..)` statement to a separate variable:

```py
KeyTypeStr = constr(regex="^[a-zA-Z0-9_]*$")
KeyOutputStr = constr(regex="^[a-zA-Z0-9_]*$")

class RedisSettings(BaseModel):
    keyInput: KeyTypeStr = "" 
    keyOutput: KeyOutputStr = ""
```

It looks even cleaner like that, and the type annotation can be reused easily, even in other modules.

Answer (score 0):

Follow:

- [`typing.Annotated` Fields](https://docs.pydantic.dev/usage/schema/#typingannotated-fields)

How about:

```py
from typing import Annotated

from pydantic import BaseModel, Field


class RedisSettings(BaseModel):
    keyInput: Annotated[str, Field(regex=r"^\w*$")] = ""
    keyOutput: Annotated[str, Field(regex=r"^\w*$")] = ""
```